# MySQL Regex Replace Query

Tags: mysql

I have a field with this value:

```
TEST:ATEST:TESTA
```

And I want to replace "TEST" with "NEW", I have tried this query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, 'TEST', 'NEW') WHERE `field` REGEXP 'TEST';
```

The result was:

```
NEW:ANEW:NEWA
```

Q: How could I do the replacement query so the result would be like this:

```
NEW:ATEST:TESTA
```

Comment: So the text `TEST` may appear in any place or just on the first place ?

Comment: please consider following solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: Good catch @Abhikda, +1, So if TEST appear in first place we can use  “^” to match the beginning

Comment: @Abhik It may appear in any place and some times the whole field would be the "TEST" word only.

Comment: @iTesTi with regex you can select the data but can not modify it. You need some sort string manipulation for that purpose, check answer from Gordon.

Comment: do you have unique `id` column in your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit of a pain, but you can do it this way:

```
UPDATE `table`
    SET field = substr(REPLACE(concat(':', field, ':'), ':TEST:', ':NEW:'),
                       2, length(REPLACE(concat(':', field, ':'), ':TEST:', ':NEW:')) - 2)
    WHERE concat(':', field, ':') LIKE '%:TEST:%';
```

I prefer `LIKE` to `REGEXP` because there is the hope of being able to use an index.  That is not a possibility in this case, but there is the hope.

This is delimiting the values with colons at the beginning and the end, and only replacing fully delimited values.  The trick is to then remove the additional colons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e66b/3

so the update query is (if table name = table1, field name = field1, and there is unique column id):

```
UPDATE `table1` 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id, 
    @set_idx:=FIND_IN_SET('TEST',REPLACE(field1,':',',')),
    @set_size:=LENGTH(field1)-LENGTH(REPLACE(field1,':',''))+1,
    CASE 
      WHEN @set_idx=1 THEN CONCAT('NEW',SUBSTRING(field1, 4))
      WHEN @set_idx>1 THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, ':',@set_idx-1),':NEW', IF(@set_size>@set_idx,CONCAT(':',SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1, ':',-(@set_size-@set_idx))),''))
    END as new
  FROM table1
  WHERE `field1` REGEXP '(^TEST$)|(^TEST:)|(:TEST$)|(:TEST:)'
   ) t
ON t.id = table1.id
SET table1.field1 = t.new;
```